# Picklist and Text IF Formula

Tags: formula, formula-field

I'm having trouble with a `IF` formula that I am asking to search for these specific values to return two types of students but I am receiving an error that I am missing part of my expression. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong here? I simply want it to meet all these values and produce "international" or "domestic" below:

Student type is a picklist field

Status is a picklist field

Owner is a text/lookup to a user

```
IF(ISPICKVAL( Student_Type__c ,"First-time Freshman"),
IF(ISPICKVAL( Student_Type__c ,"First-time Freshman with College Work"),
IF(ISPICKVAL( Status__c   ,"Freshman"),
IF(ISPICKVAL( Status__c   ,"Freshman with College Work"),
IF(CONTAINS("Melissa:Holly:Robert",Owner__c), "International","Domestic"))))))
```

Comment: Do you just want all the conditions to be true? One picklist field cannot concurrently hold two values.

Comment: Logically  it should read out like this :If Type=Firstime freshman or first time freshman with college work and Status = freshman or freshamn with college work, and Owner is Melissa or holly or robert, then International, else Domestic

Comment: Can you post the ***verbatim*** compile error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formula will never return true. One picklist field can never simultaneously have two options selected.

You haven't given the error text, which makes  the specific problem harder to identify, but I think the following might more closely represent what you are looking for:

```
IF(
    AND(
        // all inner clauses must be true for the whole to be true
        OR(
            // either inner clause must be true for the whole to be true
            ISPICKVAL(PicklistField1__c, "Option 1"),
            ISPICKVAL(PicklistField1__c, "Option 2")
        ),
        OR(
            // either inner clause must be true for the whole to be true
            ISPICKVAL(PicklistField2__c, "Option A"),
            ISPICKVAL(PicklistField2__c, "Option B")
        ),
        CONTAINS("X:Y:Z", Owner__c)
    ),
    "International", // value if all the above is true
    "Domestic" // value if all the above is false
)
```

As I learned from [@sfdcfox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2984/sfdcfox), you can shave some compile size with some fancy restructuring:

```
IF(3 =
    CASE(PicklistField1__c, "Option 1", 1, "Option 2", 1, 0) +
    CASE(PicklistField2__c, "Option A", 1, "Option B", 1, 0) +
    IF(CONTAINS("X:Y:Z", Owner__c), 1, 0), "International", "Domestic"
)
```

Comment: ... and I saw your edit right after I submitted what you just wrote.

Comment: I debated whether to lead with the 3 or not. I think it does look better that way. And I'm glad you taught me that one. You know all the best tricks. :)

Comment: I know I don't know all the tricks, but optimization is one of my life's passions. I like to see how something works, then I like to make it work *better*.

Comment: I dig it. You gonna be at #DF16?

Comment: Yes, I'm going to be there, and I can't wait!

Comment: Me neither. It'll be good to meet some Stack Exchangers in real life! My first time attending.

Comment: It'll be my first, too. I've tried to go every year since 2005, but never had the money, time, whatever. If you're going to any of the parties, we'll probably run in to each other there. I like my parties.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Isn't `Owner__c` here would be an Id?

Comment: @Oleksiy That's certainly not clear based on the post. `OwnerId` is, but for all we know, `Owner__c` is a formula for `Owner.FirstName` or some such.

Comment: @AdrianLarson This is exactly what solved my issue. Thank you so much! +1